# Special case of Eichler–Shimura

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

I'm reading ‘[Rational Points on Elliptic Curves](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-18588-0)’ by Silverman and Tate, and the exercise 4.6 is about the following special case of the Eichler–Shimura theorem. Let $C$ be the elliptic curve given by the equation $C: y^2 = x^3-4x^2+16$ and let $F(q)$ be the formal power series given by the infinite product $F(q) = q \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^n)^2(1-q^{11n})^2$. Let $N_n$ be the coefficient of $q^n$ in $F(q)$, so $F(q)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty N_n q^n$. The exercise is to prove that $M_p+N_p=p$, where $M_p$ is the number of points on $C$ over the field $\mathbb{F}_p$. So, what is the idea of proof? Because I have no ideas how $M_p$ and $N_p$ can be connected.

Comment: This question is double-starred in the exercise. This is of the same difficulty as Eichler-Shimura.

Comment: The exercise is equivalent to the statement that the $L(s,C)=L(s,F)$. On a smaller note, please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault so maybe you know where i can read proof of this theorem? thanks!

Comment: @GHfromMO what is $L(s, F)?$ I know only about L-functions for elliptic curves

Comment: Read Iwaniec's "topics" book (https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-17), especially Chapter 8. Note also that L-functions of modular forms are more fundamental than L-functions of elliptic curves (although many colleagues would disagree).

Comment: @GHfromMO thank you! So Hecke characters are necessary to obtain relation between $M_p$ and $N_p$?

Comment: It is hard to tell what is needed for a proof before finding the proof. You will see more clearly after you have read the chapter I recommended.

Comment: I believe the modularity of this elliptic curve is well explain in [these notes](https://swc-math.github.io/notes/files/01Weston1.pdf). The curve in question here is isomorphic to $y^2+y=x^3-x$, which is shown to be the equation of $X_1(11)$. You will see this is really a bit more difficult than the level of Silverman-Tate, yet the notes give a good introduction into the subject.

Comment: @Dendrit Eichler-Shimura tells you that the $L$-function of the modular form $F(q)$ is equal to the $L$-function of the elliptic curve $X_0(11)$. This elliptic curve is isogenous to $X_1(11)$, which is itself isomorphic to $C$ (on a historical note, an equation of $X_0(11)$ has been determined by Fricke around 1920). This gives you the result.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich thank you for link! But modularity means only that such product exists, am I right? Or it is possible to somehow deduce from modularity explicit formula for $F(q)$?

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault thanks! But what is $X_0(11)$ and $X_1(11)$?

Comment: @Dendrit This is explained in the notes linked to by Chris Wuthrich.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault ok, thanks, i will try to study